# How to correctly implement tf.data from generator with multiple inputs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.data.dataset

I have created a custom generator for a siamese network which feeds the network triplets of images:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):

...preprocessing of anchors positive and negative matches
    
return anchors, positives, negatives
```

What is the correct way to create a tf.data Dataset from generator?
My attempt below results in errors in the generator if I wrap the triplet in a tuple/list.

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
lambda: train_gen, 
output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32), 
output_shapes=([None,224,224,3], [None,224,224,3], [None,224,224,3])
```

But if I do, I get the same error but from the model when I feed it `ds`.

```
Layer model expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

The error is self-explanatory. I just don't understand how
if I do `[a, p, n]` I get it from the `tf.data.dataset.from_generator()` function when creating the dataset but not when I call `.fit(ds)` but then when using `.predict(ds)`

I appreciate any points you can provide, thanks!

Comment: Is there a need to add lambda? And can you show how you wrote your earlier generator, from the looks of it are you using keras sequence generator?

Comment: try printing out your generator and check if you have 3 inputs

Comment: Hi Edwin, thanks! I tried that, it does. Without lambda it doesn't work. According to the docs and stackoverflow (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) this is the way to get around parsing a generator as an iterator

Comment: I have a question is there any need to use a generator? Can you just bypass it and use a tensor slices function? and you can do any mapping with the map function

Comment: I found that more convenient, because I just have a dataframe with the filepaths and I've done it a couple of times before (I used tensor slices too but from memory). I'll try figuring out a way to do it with tensorslices. Thank you very much!

Comment: @EdwinCheong I looked into creating tensor_slices today, but it seems like as I feared it's needed that the data be in array format but with image datasets that seems a little unfeasible. Which is also why I created the generator to read the images in batches from filepath arrays. Would you know of a solution?

Comment: Sure but from tensor slices does as accept numpy arrays as an input

Comment: You can use the map function to read and process your images, but maybe you can share some more details

Comment: @EdwinCheong thanks a lot, I was able to figure out how to use map with tf.io.read_file(img) and tf.decode_image but it doesn't work using map on this function which does the same thing but enables me to use my earlier transforms:
`def process_img(img):
    return cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: I think the issue is that the filename is a tensor, but I can work around it by calling np.array(img) on the tensor and then doing the transforms

Comment: Seems like you solve the issue great